# If condition not detecting operator

Tags: linux, bash

Today I have started to learn to write bash shell scripts, and the prof has tasked us to create a simple script calculator using three inputs: two of which are numeric inputs and one is an operator input.

First, to my understanding, when a variable is assigned from reading input, it is treated as a string. so then by comparing the variable `op` to the string version of `+` it should evaluate `n1+n2`. however this is not the case, and I get the following errors:

`./q2.txt: line 9: [+: command not found`

`./q2.txt: line 13: [+: command not found`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the operator"
read op
echo "Enter the first number"
read n1
echo "Enter second number"
read n2

if ["$op" == "+"]
then
    n3=$((n1+n2))

elif [$op = "-"]
then
    n3 = $((n1-n2))

fi
echo "Answer: $n3"

exit 0
```

Comment: Have you tried using `eval`?

Comment: @wallyk we were instructed to use $((var)) for this lesson

Comment: The `echo` + `read` could be written in one statement as: `read -r -p 'Enter number> ' n1`. Also, you even not need the comparison at all, just use `n3=$(($n1 $op $n2))` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the if syntax must left a space before and after  condition `[ condition ]`

so your script will be

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the operator"
read op
echo "Enter the first number"
read n1
echo "Enter second number"
read n2

if [ "$op" == "+" ]
then
    n3=$((n1+n2))

elif [ $op = "-" ]
then
    n3 = $((n1-n2))

fi
echo "Answer: $n3"

exit 0
```

Then it will works

Comment: oh my gosh i cant believe it was that trivial. thanks

Comment: you're welcome @user3170251